# How to prove that $B(n) < n!$ for all $n \geq 3$ where $B(n)$ is $n$-th Bell number

Tags: combinatorics, stirling-numbers, bell-numbers

When I approached this problem I thought that it can be easily solved by applying induction. However something went completely wrong and I haven’t managed to prove it by induction.

Maybe there is some different way to approach this problem? Any kind of help will be much appreciated

Comment: What properties of the Bell numbers are you allowed to use? For example, the recurrence formula $B_{n+1} = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom n k B_k$?

Comment: @player3236 I am not sure that I am allowed to use this formula but if there is no other way to prove it then why not

Comment: or perhaps you want a combinatorial proof?

Comment: @player3236 It is absolutely not compulsory but it would be really cool for sure

Comment: It's really easy as a combinatorial rather than an algebraic problem. $\qquad$

Comment: @player3236 : I wonder if you should up-vote this question?

Comment: @MichaelHardy At least I didn't down-vote the question.

Comment: @player3236 : Somebody did and I wonder why.

Comment: Here. Now you get a +1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This inequality just says that there more permutations than partitions of the set $[n]=\{1,\ldots,n\}.$

Every permutation of $[n]$ has cycles. Every cycle is a permutation of some subset of $[n].$ Those subsets are disjoint, so they form a partition of $[n].$ But this mapping from permutations to partitions is not one-to-one. For example:
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
\text{permutation} & & \text{partition} \\[8pt]
\hline
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & \to & 2 \\
\uparrow & \swarrow \\
4 & & 3
\end{array}
\right] &
\mapsto & \Big\{ \{1,2,4,\},\,\,\, \{3\} \Big\} \\[12pt]
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & \leftarrow & 2 \\
\downarrow & \nearrow \\
4 & & 3
\end{array}
\right] & \mapsto & \Big\{ \{1,2,4\},\,\,\, \{3\}\Big\}
\end{array}
$$
Different permutations can be mapped to the same partition.

So there are more permutations than partitions.

Comment: As a bonus, we also see that this argument requires a $(\ge3)$-cycle, so it works for $n\ge3$ only.

Comment: Thanks! But could you, please, explain what do you mean by cycle in permutation?

Comment: @math-traveler : A permutation is a one-to-one function $f$ from $[n]$ onto itself. For each $k\in[n],$ there the sequence $k,\,f(k),\,f(f(k)),\,f(f(f(k))),\,\ldots$ cannot have infinitely many distinct terms since they're all within the finite set $[n].$ Nor can any term be equal to an earlier term other than the first term, because $f$ is one-to-one. Therefore the sequence contains distinct terms until you get $f(f(f(\cdots (f(k)) \cdots ))) = k.$ It starts at $k$ and returns to $k.$ That is a cycle. Thus in the first example above,$\,\ldots \qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$Thus in the first example above, you have $f(1)=2,\,f(2)=4,\,f(4)=1.$ That is a cycle. And $f(3)=3$ and that is another cycle. Those two cycles are the two parts of a partition of $[4] = \{1,2,3,4,\}. \qquad$

Answer (score 2):

OP's supposed attempt in proving this confused me, and the only proof by induction that came into mind uses the recurrence relation
$$B_{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom nkB_k$$

We need strong induction, and $B_1=1!, B_2 = 2!$. The base case $n=3$ is trivial.

The induction step goes as follows:

$$B_{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom nkB_k\le\sum_{k=0}^n \frac {n!}{(n-k)!k!}k!< \sum_{k=0}^n n!=(n+1)!$$

Comment: Oh, are you sure that your last step was correct? Is $\sum_{k=0}^{n}n! = (n+1)!$. I just checked it on small numbers, and it didn't work. For example: $0! + 1! + 2! + 3! = 10 \not= 4!$. Probably you meant $\sum_{k=0}^{n}n! < (n+1)!$

Comment: Nope. $n!$ does not depend on $k$, and we have $3!+3!+3!+3!=4!$.

Comment: Oh... True, I am sorry(

Answer (score 0):

At least for large values of $n$, you could use
$$\frac{\ln B_n}{n}  \sim \ln n - \ln \ln n - 1 $$ while
$$\frac{\ln n!}{n}  \sim \ln n-1 $$ and $ln ln 3 =0.094$